# How to dynamically apply inline styles based on runtime data in draft js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wysiwyg, draftjs

In my application, I have a backend server where I send all the text entered in the draft js editor and the server returns tokens for the text. Based on these tokens I want to style the text. How do I do that in draft js?

Approach 1:
I tried using decorators where I have a map that I fill up based on the token types and text and the decorator function uses this map to apply styles to all the text. However, the decorator is always one step behind as it is working with previous onChange's data. There is no way to manually trigger a decorate().

Approach 2:
If I want to use Richutils, it automatically uses the current selection to toggle inline styles. In my case there is no selection, so that won't work.

I am just looking for a simple function that can apply inline styles based on character index/offset. something like

```
editorState = Richutils.applyInlineStyle(editorState, indexstart, length (or indexend), style);
```

Is there any other way I can achieve this. It seems a perfectly doable and reasonable thing to have supported, but artificially restricted.

Answer (score 0):

`https://draftjs.org/docs/api-reference-modifier/#applyinlinestyle` is excatly the function you need.

```js
applyInlineStyle(
  contentState: ContentState,
  selectionState: SelectionState,
  inlineStyle: string
): ContentState
```